# No MODULE named markup://lgc:bg found : [markup://c:accountManagerApex]

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have created LWC for showing accounts and created one Lighting web component and one apex class shown below.
**Html file**

```
   <template>
    <lightning-card title="Showing Account(tile)">
        <template if:true={successResponse}>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                <li key={account.id}>
                    <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                        <lightning-tile label={account.Name} href="/path/to/somewhere">
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title={account.Phone}>Account's Phone Number is : 

{account.Phone}
                            </p>
                        </lightning-tile>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Js.file**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import allAccount from "@salesforce/apex/AcountManager.getAccount"

export default class AccountManagerApex extends LightningElement {

  @wire(allAccount)
  accountRecrd;

  successResponse (){
    if(this.accountRecrd){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

**and Class is:**

public with sharing class AcountManager {

```
    @AuraEnabled( cacheable = true) 
    public static List<Account> getAccount(){

        return [SELECT Id,Name,Phone,Website FROM Account Limit 10];
    }
}
```

When I try to deploy to my org using VSCode I'm getting the below error.

***Error***

**force-app\main\default\lwc\accountManagerApex\accountManagerApex.js  No MODULE named markup://lgc:bg found : [markup://c:accountManagerApex]**

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue/

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `<isExposed>true</isExposed>` inside meta.xml file of the component

Answer (score 2):

You have a custom css class `lgc-bg`. Please make sure your css file has a period before the selector

```css
/* incorrect, lwc tries to find lgc:bg component */
lgc-bg : {}
/* correct */
.lgc-bg {}
```